# Azure DevOps add an overview

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-marketplace

I'm just trying to add an overview of my custom extension. A step-by-step guide, etc.

Also, it would be great to know, how to add Q&A tab.

Currently, it seems like on a screen below.

[image: overview]

I would like to add an Overview, but I don't know how to do it.

My `vss-extension.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "{{my id}}",
    "version": "{{version}}",
    "name": "{{name}}",
    "description": "{{description}}",
    "publisher": "{{publisher}}",
    "categories": [
        "Azure Boards"
    ],
    "includes": [
        "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-service-data-external"
    ],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "static/logo.png"
    },
    "demands": [
        "contribution/ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-sdk-version-2",
        "contribution/ms.vss-web.charts-service"
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "Widget",
            "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog",
                ".Configuration"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "{{name}}",
                "description": "A reusable widget",
                "catalogIconUrl": "static/catalogImage.png",
                "previewImageUrl": "static/previewImage.png",
                "isNameConfigurable": false,
                "uri": "static/widget.html",
                "supportedSizes": [
                    {
                        "rowSpan": 2,
                        "columnSpan": 2
                    }
                ],
                "supportedScopes": [
                    "project_team"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "Configuration",
            "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-configuration",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-configuration"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "AnalyticsExampleWidget Configuration",
                "description": "Configures AnalyticsExampleWidget",
                "uri": "static/configuration.html"
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overview is a `readme.md` file that you need to put in the extension repo and specify the path in the `vss-extension.json` file:

```
"content": {
    "details": {
    "path": "README.MD"
    },
```

The Q & A section is not configurable, users can go there and create a question, you can answer.